# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib - Ionic | Razorpay Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3, razorpay

I am trying to integrate Razorpay cordova plugin in my ionic app. It works find for Android. But for iOS I am getting below error when I run the app in Xcode. I am unable to proceed further. Please help me resolve the same. FYI, I have integrated as per the steps mentioned in the integration video and have added Razorpay framework in "Embedded Binaries" and have updated "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" to "Yes"

Error Msg:
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib

Referenced from: /Users//Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B12116FD-C014-41B6-A5BF-6CEE7F079850/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A76F064E-8CCA-4F93-A6CC-6E2C140CC231/The SICA.app/Frameworks/Razorpay.framework/Razorpay

Reason: image not found

IDE Specs
Xcode: 10.1
Swift version: 4.2.1
Razorpay Version: 1.4.8 (com.razorpay.cordova)

[Screenshot - 1 - Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9CRf.png)

[Screenshot - 2 - Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdA1v.png)

Answer (score 1):

> Update X-code version to the latest `11.3.1` and ensure that you have the framework added in Frameworks, Libraries, and
>   Embed Content under Target settings - General.

Change Embed value of **Razorpay.framework** under Frameworks, Libraries, and Embed Content from `'Do not Embed' -> 'Embed & Sign'.`

[image: Embed & Sign']

[image: Framework]